# Show film description with string format

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers, string-concatenation

I have a task need to write a trigger statement with format
[image]

This is my database schema:
[image]

I write my code like

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER "BI_FILM_DESP"
BEFORE INSERT ON "FILM"
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
RatingFilm VARCHAR2(8);
Seq NUMBER(3);
OriginalL VARCHAR2(20);
Language VARCHAR2(20);
BEGIN
SELECT RATING INTO RatingFilm FROM FILM F;
SELECT COUNT(RATING) INTO Seq FROM FILM F GROUP BY F.RATING;
SELECT LANGUAGE.NAME INTO OriginalL FROM LANGUAGE L WHERE (L.LANGUAGE_ID =: FILM.LANGUAGE_ID);
SELECT LANGUAGE.NAME INTO Language FRoM LANGUAGE L WHERE (L.LANGUAGE_ID =: FILM.LANGUAGE_ID);
SELECT CONCAT(RatingFilm, "-", Seq, ": Originally in", OriginalL, ". Re-released in ", Language, ".");
END;
/
```

However it shows error
[image]

I think it's hard to read those errors and I need some help to correct it. Thanks in advance.

---

Edit: Add code that create tables

```
CREATE TABLE film (
  film_id NUMBER(5) NOT NULL,
  title varchar2(255),
  description varchar2(255),
  release_year NUMBER(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  language_id NUMBER(3) NOT NULL,
  original_language_id NUMBER(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  rental_duration NUMBER(3) DEFAULT 3 NOT NULL,
  rental_rate NUMBER(4,2) DEFAULT '4.99' NOT NULL,
  length NUMBER(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  replacement_cost NUMBER(5,2) DEFAULT '19.99' NOT NULL,
  rating varchar2(8) DEFAULT 'G' NOT NULL,
  special_features varchar2(255) DEFAULT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE language (
  language_id NUMBER(3) NOT NULL,
  name varchar2(20)
);
```

Comment: (1) MySQL <> OracleDB, tags list edited (2) In `SELECT LANGUAGE.NAME INTO OriginalL FROM LANGUAGE L WHERE (L.LANGUAGE_ID =: FILM.LANGUAGE_ID);` the table `FILM` is not mentioned as rowsource in FROM clause. (3) In row-based trigger you must refer to `NEW` pseudotables for current row values accessing.

Comment: 1) In Oracle strings should be enclosed with single quotes `'`, double quotes are for identifiers. 2) You cannot select from nowhere, you should use `from dual` when you need some constants. 3) You cannot access the same table inside the trigger with `for each row`, you'll get mutating table error. 4) `select` without filter will return more than one row, which cannot be placed into scalar variables. So there is too much to fix, try to build your solution step by step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope you read astentx's comment.

Here's how you could/should do it.

Tables involved (with necessary columns only):

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE language
  2  (
  3     language_id   NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
  4     name          VARCHAR2 (20)
  5  );

Table created.

SQL> INSERT INTO language (language_id, name)
  2     SELECT 1, 'English' FROM DUAL
  3     UNION ALL
  4     SELECT 2, 'Croatian' FROM DUAL;

2 rows created.

SQL> CREATE TABLE film
  2  (
  3     film_id                NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
  4     title                  VARCHAR2 (20),
  5     description            VARCHAR2 (100),
  6     language_id            NUMBER REFERENCES language,
  7     original_language_id   NUMBER REFERENCES language,
  8     rating                 NUMBER
  9  );

Table created.
```

Trigger: don't select from table on which that row-level trigger fires as you'd get mutating table error. Good for you, you don't have to do that - use `:new` pseudorecord values instead:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER bi_film_desp
  2     BEFORE INSERT
  3     ON film
  4     FOR EACH ROW
  5  DECLARE
  6     l_language           language.name%TYPE;
  7     l_original_language  language.name%TYPE;
  8  BEGIN
  9     SELECT l.name
 10       INTO l_language
 11       FROM language l
 12      WHERE l.language_id = :new.language_id;
 13
 14     SELECT l.name
 15       INTO l_original_language
 16       FROM language l
 17      WHERE l.language_id = :new.original_language_id;
 18
 19     :new.description :=
 20           'Rating: '
 21        || :new.rating
 22        || ', original language: '
 23        || l_original_language
 24        || ', language: '
 25        || l_language;
 26  END;
 27  /

Trigger created.

SQL>
```

Let's test it:

```
SQL> INSERT INTO film (film_id,
  2                    title,
  3                    language_id,
  4                    original_language_id,
  5                    rating)
  6       VALUES (1,
  7               'Izbavitelj',
  8               1,
  9               2,
 10               7);

1 row created.
```

Result:

```
SQL> select title, description, rating from film;

TITLE      DESCRIPTION                                                      RATING
---------- ------------------------------------------------------------ ----------
Izbavitelj Rating: 7, original language: Croatian, language: English             7

SQL>
```

Looks OK to me.

Comment: But my `rating` in film table is `varchar2(8)` type. That's why I need to use `COUNT` to show how many times the rating exists. For example the rating is "PG' and it already exists in the table 4 times, then when I add another record with rating = "PG". seq should show 5. Is it the right way to show this?